# Centos takes very long time to resolve local network nearby servers

Tags: linux, dns, centos

i have few Centos 5.1 servers, recently they took very long time to communicate eachother, it looks like for every request it checks local server in public dns, is there is anyway to give option in /etc/resolve.conf to disable dns for some IP address ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the server names and their IP addresses to the file **/etc/hosts**, e.g.

```
10.0.0.100        server1 server1-alias
10.0.0.101        server2
```

and then make sure that you list the keyword **files** before the keyword **dns** for the *hosts* entry in **/etc/nsswitch.conf**, i.e. that file should have a line that looks something like this:

```
hosts:           files dns
```

After that, any attempts to resolve hostnames or IP addresses will first consult the /etc/hosts file, and only if that is unsuccessful go on to do a DNS lookup.